# Single speed crank chainline calculation

Tags: chainline

I apologise ahead of time for yet ANOTHER single speed chainline/crank compatibility question.

I have a Genesis Day One 2013. According to online [sources](https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/bikes/cyclocross-bikes/genesis-day-one-disc-review/) the crankset for this bike is the [Driveline TX-13](https://www.driveline.com.tw/product/13/56).

The specs for this crankset are (according to the current [Driveline website](https://www.driveline.com.tw/product/13/56)):

- Length - 170mm
- BCD - 130mm
- Chainline - 45mm
- BB Axle - Square (103)

I have measured my bike, and it has the following relevant dimensions:

- 135mm rear hub spacing
- 45mm chainline (measured from centre of seat tube to centre of chainring tooth)
- 68mm bottom bracket housing width
- 110mm bottom bracket spindle length

This doesn't make sense to me because the Driveline website gives a 45mm chainline on a 103mm spindle, but I have a 45mm chainline on a 110mm spindle. Have I misunderstood/miscalculated something?

Maybe the P1 designation on the Driveline website indicates that the current model is different from the 2013 version used on  my bike?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most plausible explanation is that the crank design has changed since 2013. Other explanation could be that it is actually a different crank. The TK13 is a generic singlespeed crank that looks almost the same as similar cranks from other brands, so it is possible that Genesis could have changed to different supplier without Cycling Plus knowing it.

In both cases, trust the measurements over specifications.